# I'm trying to insert some HTML into jodit-react editor on my cursor position, it somehow inserts but not exactly at my cursor position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, jodit

I'm trying to insert the following block on the cursor position:

**Inserted Text**

I've used following methods to get the exact cursor position:

- **this.jodit.selectionStart**
- window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset

my function buttonClick inserts it inside the line but is unable to recapture the changed cursor position when I try inserting it.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import jodit from "jodit";
import "./App.css";
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: "",
      pos: 0,
    };
  }

  updateContent = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      content: value,
      pos: window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset,
    });
  };
  buttonClick = (event) => {
    var abc = this.state.content.slice(
      this.jodit.selectionStart,
      this.jodit.selectionEnd + 1
    );
    var startString = this.state.content.substring(0, this.state.pos + 3);
    var endString = this.state.content.substring(this.jodit.selectionEnd);
    console.log("abc" + startString + "::::::" + endString);
    this.setState({
      content: startString + '<a href="#">Inserted Text</a>' + endString,
    });
  };
  config = {
    readonly: false,
  };
  /**
   * @property Jodit jodit instance of native Jodit
   */
  jodit;
  setRef = (jodit) => (this.jodit = jodit);
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <JoditEditor
          ref={this.setRef}
          value={this.state.content}
          config={this.config}
          tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
          onBlur={this.onFocusRemove}
          onChange={this.updateContent}
        />
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>insert</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also tried the above code with this.jodit.selectionstart instead ofwindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset but issue remained.

According to what I analysed, onChange handler updates the cursor position whenever we input something, but when we change the cursor position it do not update it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below in the config object

```
config = {
      readonly: false, // all options from https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/
      events: 
           { 
            afterInit: (instance) => { this.jodit = instance; } 

}


buttonClick = (event) => { 
     this.jodit.selection.insertHTML('<a href="">Anchor Tag</a>'); 
};
```

This way you will get instance of editor after afterInit.
This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

To insert text at the cursor position inside Jodit Editor when a button is clicked, you can use the "insertHTML" method. Here is an example of how you can do this in ReactJS:
First, import the Jodit Editor module:
**import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react';**

Next, define a function that will be called when the button is clicked. This function should use the "insertHTML" method to insert the desired text at the cursor position:

```js
const insertText = () => {
   joditEditor.editor.selection.insertHTML('<p>Inserted Text</p>');
}
```

In your JSX code, add a button that calls the "insertText" function when clicked:

```html
<button onClick={insertText}>Insert Text</button>
```

Finally, render the Jodit Editor component and assign it to a variable (in this case, "joditEditor"):

```html
<JoditEditor ref={(editor) => joditEditor = editor} />
```

Note: You may need to wrap the "insertHTML" method in a try/catch block to handle any potential errors.